# C# runtime error: index out of range

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I have to make a simple windows forms application in which the player takes turns with the computer in taking sticks (which I made out of labels which go invisible), but I am having a problem with the code for the pc as it causes a runtime error "index out of range", and I can't figure it out..

```
    private void pcTake(int x)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "I take " + x;
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
        {
            if (labels[i].Visible == false && labels[i + 1].Visible == true)
            {
                while (x > 0)
                {
                    if (x + i > labels.Count)
                        break;
                    labels[i + x].Visible = false;
                    x--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

*x* is a random number,
*labels* is a list containing the labels

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Label)
            {
                labels.Add(c);
                c.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint, kept track of the values of i and x, and figured out which line of code is erroring out?  Step 1 in troubleshooting this error is knowing what array index you're accessing, and the length of the array.  For info on breakpoints see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the exception beause of your comparison

```
labels[i + 1].Visible == true
```

since your loop is based on  `< labels.Count`, that means when the loop index reaches to `count - 1`, your condition is suppose to check array index on `count` (because of `i + 1`), since array's index is 0 based, you are getting the exception.

If you want to check the current index and later index then your loop condition should be `i < labels.Count - 1` like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count - 1; i++)
```

Comment: ...I am really stupid not to have seen that, thanks;
now another problem turned up, the labels that are supposed to disappear do not.. any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

In C#, arrays are 0-indexed, so the last item is labels[labels.Count-1]; you should change this

```
if (x + i > labels.Count)
    break;
```

into this

```
if (x + i > labels.Count -1)
    break;
```